# How to redirect from a controller using a named URL mapping?

Tags: grails, grails-controller, url-mapping

I have a URL mapping as below:

```
static mappings = {
        name register: "/register" {
            controller = "account"
            action = "createuser"
        }
}
```

and I want to redirect using this mapping from a controller with something like:

```
redirect mapping:'register'
```

Unfortunately, unlike [createLink](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) tag lib, it seems that [redirect](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) does not accept `mapping` as input parameter.

So my question is : How can I use my named URL mapping for redirection ?

Comment: Curious why you need to do it by the mapping vs redirect(controller:'account', action:'createUser')

Comment: Because, if I change my register mapping, I will not have to change the code but only url mappings. Also, code is more readable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the two:

```
redirect url: createLink(mapping: 'register')
```

Comment: If the application name (e.g. app.name set in application.properties) is part of the url, then you will need to add the parameter `absolute: true` to the createLink call, to avoid having the application show up twice in the resulting redirect (eg http://localhost:8080/myapp/myapp/register)